# Using PDFBox to find the largest rect border form my pdf file converted form DWG

Tags: pdfbox

I have a pdf file converted from DWG file.
I want to find the largest rect border line in this pdf file.
With PDFBox I have the following code.

```
//PDFGraphicsStreamEngine.java#lineTo
    @Override
public void lineTo(float x, float y) throws IOException {
    System.out.printf("lineTo %.2f %.2f\n", x, y);
    x0 = Math.min(x0, x);
    y0 = Math.min(y0, y);

    x1 = Math.max(x1, x);
    y1 = Math.max(y1, y);
}
float x0 = Float.MAX_VALUE, y0 = Float.MAX_VALUE;
float x1 = Float.MIN_VALUE, y1 = Float.MIN_VALUE;
```

This code works fine **only if the file is not rotated**! I have little knowledge of `PDF Coordinate System` or `Matrix`. So the questions is:

1. How to make this code work with rotated pdf(e.g. [my pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FwB0jSOt8QFibMux6RxdtWPGA_uhlOyU/view?usp=sharing))

**Detail Info**:

I want to find the following points ABCD where the RectABCD is the largest rect that been drawn in this pdf.
[image]

Comment: This is more a math problem. Get the length of a line with this weird ancient trick: `float lineLength = (float) Math.sqrt(((x1 - x0) * (x1 - x0)) + ((y1 - y0) * (y1 - y0)));`

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I add detail info. I cannot get your point. Any more explanation? Many thanks.

Comment: That is a different question now. Previously you asked for the largest border line. Now you ask for the largest rect surface. This now a much trickier problem... you'd need an algorithm to decide whether a group of lines are a rectangle. Btw there's not just lineto, there's also appendRectangle().